# Sending emails using gapi (typescript) displays wrong encoded emails in Sent box

Tags: angular, typescript, encoding, google-api-js-client

I am sending out emails using gapi. The receiver receives them correctly, but when I start looking at my "Sent" box they just look like Chinese gibberish characters. Like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLsI3.jpg)

To be more specific, it looks only like this when I use non-gmail applications. So if I look in my Sent box in gmail it looks fine, however if I use outlook or if I use my Android's default Mail app and connect it with my gmail account and look at the Sent folder it's totally messed up. Clearly it has something to do with encoding, but apparently gmail manages to fix it and the other app don't.

Here's the code I use to send an email:

```
async sendMail(email, files) {
    //create cc and bcc string if needed
    let ccStr = `Cc: ${email.cc}\r\n`
    let bccStr = `Bcc: ${email.bcc}\r\n`

    //create attachment if needed
    let attachStr = await this.createAttachmentStr(files)
    attachStr = `${attachStr}\r\n\r\n`

    //create the message
    let message = 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="#split-part#"\r\n' +
      'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
      `To: ${email.to}\r\n` +
      `From: ${email.from}\r\n` +
      ccStr +
      bccStr +
      `Subject: ${email.subject}\r\n\r\n` +
      '--#split-part#\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n' +
      'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' +
      `${email.message}\r\n\r\n` +
      `${attachStr}` +
      '--#split-part#--'

    //base64url encode
    const encodedMessage = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(message))).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '')

    //send to api
    gapi.client["gmail"].users.messages.send({
      'userId': 'me',
      'resource': {
        'raw': encodedMessage,
        "payload": {
          "mimeType": 'multipart/mixed'
        },
        'threadId': email.id
      }
    }).then(async response => {
      //do some stuff after
    })
  }
```

the method used in there called createAttachmentStr based of a FileList:

```
createAttachmentStr(files: FileList): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
      let attachStr = ""

      //initialize counter
      let count = 0

      //loop through each file
      if (files && files.length > 0) {
        Array.from(files).forEach(async file => {
          //convert file to datastrings
          let dataStr = await this.readFileContent(file)

          //get file info
          let fileName = file.name
          let contentType = file.type

          //create message str
          attachStr += '--#split-part#\r\n' +
            `Content-Type: ${contentType}\r\n` +
            'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
            `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="${fileName}"\r\n\r\n` +
            `${dataStr}\r\n\r\n`

          //increase the counter
          count++

          if (count === files.length) {
            resolve(attachStr);
          }
        });
      }
      else resolve("")
    });
  }
```

Note that this doesn't always happen, in fact it happens rarely, but I can't figure out what triggers it exactly. It seems to be related to some emails with specific attachments.

I'm kind of lost with this one so any help is appreciated

Comment: Can we see this method?  `let dataStr = await this.readFileContent(file)`

Comment: Did you have any progress with that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that it seems to be related to specific attachments, it suggests that the problem is related to the content type header of the email:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

Meaning that either (or both):

1. Some of your attachments (and possibly `email.message`) are not HTML files (which also means that those parts of the message shouldn't be passed to `encodeURIComponent`).
2. `dataStr` is not utf-8 encoded, which means that `this.readFileContent(file)` reads a file as a utf-8 encoded file, while it actually has some other encoding.

Another option is that `contentType` of some attachment files constructs an attachment header which is wrong (i.e., it doesn't correspond to the actual file type), partial (e.g., lacking the `charset="UTF-8"` part) or invalid (i.e., a non-existing content type), in the following line:

```
`Content-Type: ${contentType}\r\n`
```